# Wordpress Loop For Even/Odd Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have two columns and I want one post type to get distributed to each column evenly. So it’s two side-by-side divs and I want:

Div1 = Post1, Post3, Post5

Div2 = Post2, Post4, Post6

So basically get odd/even posts. Not exactly sure how to do it.

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=post-type'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>  
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  

<div class="column1">
<?php 
  //Get Odd Posts
?>
</div>

<div class="column2">
<?php 
  //Get Even Posts
?>
</div>

 <?php endwhile; ?>  
<?php else : ?>  
//Something that happens when a post isn’t found.  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the modulus operator something like this:

```
<?php
$i = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i <20; $i++){
    $class = $i % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd";
    echo "<div class='" . $class . "'>";

    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: The above code would produce output like this: <div class="even"></div><div class="odd"></div> until it had written 20 divs, 10 with the class odd and 10 with the class even.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, first you have to store the results somewhere (as even/odd), then display them.

Though you should really target these posts with CSS, not PHP, as it's hackish at best.

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=post-type'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>  
    <?php
        $i = 0;

        while (have_posts())
        {
            $key = $i & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even';

            $post[$key] = array(get_the_title() => get_the_content());

            $i++;
        }
    ?>
    <div class="column1">
        <?php foreach ($post['even'] as $title => $content) : ?>
            <?php echo $title; ?>
            <?php echo $content; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
        <?php foreach ($post['odd'] as $title => $content) : ?>
            <?php echo $title; ?>
            <?php echo $content; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php else : ?>  
    //Something that happens when a post isn’t found.  
<?php endif; ?>
```